# How to prevent webpages translated with Google Translate Plugin from being indexed?

Tags: robots.txt, search-engine-indexing, google-index, google-translate

I've been reading the information here https://support.google.com/translate/#2534535 about the Google Translate plugin. At first I thought that if I used the plugin my site wouldn't be indexed, but then I can see that the following quote

> The automatically translated version of your web page will not be
>   indexed by search engines.

is actually referring to [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) and not the plugin....or at least that's what I think.

**QUESTIONS**

1. I'd like to confirm whether or not websites that use the Google Translate
   Plugin are indexed.
2. If the answer is yes, then I'd like to know how to stop these
   translated pages from being indexed. I've read that you can use
   robots.txt to prevent it, but I'd really like to see an example of
   how to implement this- I'm confused as to what the translated url
   would be.

**EDIT**

Just to be clear, I don't want the translated content to be indexed. I still want the original content to be indexed!!!

Comment: Can you share a link to the site that uses this plugin?  I'm not familiar with how the plugin works, but I should be able to tell what will be indexed if I examine the site.

Comment: Sorry I can't do that- the site in question isn't live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Translator Plugin uses JavaScript to fetch translations for the page from Google servers and replace the original text dynamically.

This data is fetched from under the URL: `http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/`.  Google has a robots.txt file that prohibits crawling of `translate_a`: http://translate.googleapis.com/robots.txt

Only your English content will be indexed, not the translated content:

- Your pages are served normally with English text in the page where Googlebot can find it
- Complex JavaScript is needed to fetch the translations (Googlebot wouldn't normally do that)
- Even if Googlebot did execute the Javascript, it wouldn't fetch and index the translations as they are blocked by `robots.txt`

Comment: Wow! That is some awesome research you've done there. Much appreciated :)

Comment: That link returns a 404. Is there any other confirmation that translate_a pages won't be indexed?